# What is the minimal number of fields needed in MySQL to store geocoding data from Google Maps?

Tags: mysql, google-maps

Just to put the question in context.

I plan to have an interface where a user will provide a one line address string. I will then use the string to do a Reverse Geocoding query on the Google Maps API. I will then store the results(formatted address, address components) in the database.

My question is what is the minimum number of fields needed so that I can display addresses in formats such as mailing address, shipping address, store address, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google geocoding V2 returns LAT, LNG, and accuracy.

Use float(10,6) for the LAT and LNG, and a tinyint for the accuracy.

V3 of the API gives you a formatted address along with the LAT and LNG, see the docs and list of columns here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Take note of this; "Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited."

Comment: You should start using [spatial data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html) to store geodata.